# No me termina de cargar el front en render/vercel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

Necesito subir una aplicación Full Stack de Expres React y MySQL de manera gratuita. La base de datos ya la he conectado a db4free, pero al intentar subir la parte de front tanto a render como vercel se me queda cargando en esta parte y no avanza.

```
Nov 3 10:23:59 PM  > client@0.0.0 dev /opt/render/project/src
Nov 3 10:23:59 PM  > vite
Nov 3 10:23:59 PM  
Nov 3 10:23:59 PM  
Nov 3 10:23:59 PM    VITE v4.5.0  ready in 237 ms
Nov 3 10:23:59 PM  
Nov 3 10:23:59 PM    ➜  Local:   http:/
Nov 3 10:23:59 PM    ➜  Network: use --host to expose
```

No sé si alguien sabe por que puede ser este error. Muchas gracias.